# Show alert if two Select2 selects are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Let's say for example that I have two Select2 selects:

## Select A

Option 1
Option 2

## Select B

Option 1 Option 2

I want to capture an event when some option has been chosen for Select A and some option for Select B and then show a dismissible alert like `alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show`

I had thought to do it capturing the focus event but I have not been able to implement it, any ideas?

```
<label style="font-size: 20px;">SELECT A </label> 
<select id="selectA" class="form-control" disabled>
    <option selected>All</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
<label style="font-size: 20px;">SELECT B </label> 
<select id="selectB" class="form-control" disabled>
    <option selected>All</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

I would like to implement something like this:

```
$(function () {
  'use strict';
  $('.dropdown').on('change', function (event) {
    var selectedValue = $(event.currentTarget).val();
    var matchedDropdowns = $('.dropdown').filter(function (index) {
      return $(this).val() === selectedValue;
    });
    if (matchedDropdowns.length > 1) {
      alert("Alert Alert!")
    }
  })
})
```

The problem is that this function only compares if the two selected values are equal. I need and event for when the two selected values of the selects are different than the default value 'All', but they don't necessarily have to be equal values.

Comment: Please show us your code, ideally in a snippet.

Comment: `select2` event is what you want. You call you function after `event` and then `alert` if necessary. https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

Comment: If the traditional `alert('WARNING: some message');` in JavaScript doesn't cut it, try look at jQuery, Bootstrap Confirmation: https://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/#

Comment: @MarshalSHI Thanks, yeah I knew about select2 events, the problem is I don't know how to implement the logic when it comes to more than one select :(

Comment: Is more than one select necessary? If yes, simply do a conditional? `if(select1value != "" && select2value != ""){ //code }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies within your *conditional*. You need to check whether the 2 selects are *NOT* equal to the default value *"All"*.

inequality / not equal operator: `!=`.
Read more about expressions and operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row d-flext justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label style="font-size: 20px;">SELECT A </label> 
        <select id="selectA" class="multi-select form-control">
            <option selected>All</option>
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label style="font-size: 20px;">SELECT B </label> 
        <select id="selectB" class="multi-select form-control">
            <option selected>All</option>
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.multi-select').on("change", function() {
    var selectValA = $('#selectA').val();
    var selectValB = $('#selectB').val();

    if(selectValA != "All" && selectValB != "All") {
        alert('The value of the two selects are no longer "All"');
    }
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$('.multi-select').on("change", function() {
 var selectValA = $('#selectA').val();
 var selectValB = $('#selectB').val();
 
 if(selectValA != "All" && selectValB != "All") {
  alert('The value of the two selects are no longer "All"');
 }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row d-flext justify-content-center">
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <label style="font-size: 20px;">SELECT A </label> 
  <select id="selectA" class="multi-select form-control">
   <option selected>All</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <label style="font-size: 20px;">SELECT B </label> 
  <select id="selectB" class="multi-select form-control">
   <option selected>All</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/rNxevEw).

Answer (score 0):

I didn' test the code below. Just a kind of pseudo-code to describe what I meant in the comment.

```
// Handler get data from two select and check them
function handler() {
    var data1 = $('#selectA').select2('data');
    var data2 = $('#selectB').select2('data');
    if (data1 && data2) {
        alert("msg you want to show");
    }
}

// trigger event only
$('#selectA').on('select2:select', function (e) { handler(); });
$('#selectB').on('select2:select', function (e) { handler(); });
```

Comment: Interesting, I will try something based on your pseudo-code and let you know! Thank you